# System Error 1240 mounting network share on Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, samba, file-sharing, server-message-block

I want to share a folder from a standalone Server 2012 system on a private LAN that other servers can access without authentication.  There is no domain/AD in my environment.  This is usually a simple process that can be done with just the following 3 steps:

- enable the guest account
- share a folder with both share and system privileges set to allow Anonymous Logon
- add the share name to `Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously`

My shared folder mounts perfectly fine on other Server 2003 and Server 2012 systems. The following error occurs when I try to mount the shared folder on a Server 2008 R2 SP1 system:

```
net use * \\192.168.1.1\DeploymentShare$ /user:anyusername
System error 1240 has occurred.
The account is not authorized to log in from this station.
```

There's a [technet explanation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224287) for this error:

> This issue can occur if the non-Microsoft SMB server supports only unencrypted (plain text) passwords during authentication.

That explains what the problem is, but now how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 has `Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)` enabled by default. The error can be resolved by disabling it.  Server 2012 does not have it on by default.

Comment: I found this and a number of other useful troubleshooting tips on technet: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839499